# Changing the format of the date in mysql

Tags: mysql, date-formatting

I have a data base where I store events in a table called news has the following fields:(newsid(int), title(varchar), date(date), location(varchar), text(text). I am trying to display these events in order the most recent one on the top, I want the datesto be displayed in the form 5/6/2014 after ordering them. I tried the FORMAT function but it didn't work with me. Thanks in advance!
include("config.php");

```
//load all news from the database and then OREDER them by newsid
          $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC");
    //a loop and get all news from the database

          echo '<div id="backg">';  
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
         {//begin of loop
           //now print the results:
           echo '<br><br>';
           echo '<div class="div1">';
           echo '<p1><br><b> ';
           echo $row['title']. '</b></p1></div><br>';

           echo '<div class = "div2" style = " height : auto; min-height : 50px; height:auto !   important;height:30px;">';
           echo '<b>Time: '.'</b>';
           echo $row['time'] . '<br>';
           echo '<b>Date: '.'</b>';
           echo $row['date']. '<br>';
           echo '<b>Location: '.'</b>';
           echo $row['location'] . '<br><br>';
           echo '<p3 class="indent"><b>'.str_replace('\\n', '<br/>', $row['text1']). '</b></p3></div>';
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to format the date in the result set, and  use the "pure" unformatted date for ordering:

```
SELECT newsid, title, FORMAT_DATE(date, '%m/%e/%Y') AS DateFmt, location, text
FROM news
ORDER BY date DESC
```

The only PHP code change would be when you show the date. You need to echo the formatted value, which in the above query I've named `DateFmt`, so replace this...

```
echo $row['date']. '<br>';
```

... with this:

```
echo $row['DateFmt']. '<br>';
```

This change means you'll need to specify each column in the `SELECT` list (`SELECT a, b, c, ...` instead of `SELECT *`), but naming your columns in production code is considered good practice anyway.